# How does getClass method in Object superclass know the name of every Class?

Tags: java, object

Object superclass as I know is the mother of all Classes and all Classes implicitly extend Object. When getClass() function is invoked, how does it return the specific Class name of object on which it is invoked - Or when does the name of a Class get registered in object lifecycle?

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Sorry Dmitry, I am referring to Java

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what language you're talking about, but here are a couple options:

1. `getClass` could be a virtual method that the compiler automatically defines for every class.
2. In languages with introspection or reflection (like Java), that could be used to get the name of the class.

Comment: Hi, I was referring to Java language - sorry, did not make it clear. A bit clarification required to your reply - I would want to understand when does the Classname get set (applied) and where is it stored - I presume this is in the Class object created by JVM - Is there a Class object for every Class whose instance gets created ?

Comment: I don't really know much about the internals of the JVM or javac. The answer to your question might even depend on which JVM you use...